# Windows 10 Group Policy deploy MSI package

Tags: group-policy

I'm trying to silently deploy MSI firefox package to some domain users. I have created the group policy and linked it to desired OU, but the MSI doesn't get installed.

I'm using UNC path to the MSI file, I made sure everyone has access to the file.

In event viewer under the windows logs -> Application I'm getting this Warning:

The user 'Network' preference item in the 'Configure Users {EDD514E1-5797-42D0-9AA6-BCC7B00DFD14}' Group Policy Object did not apply because it failed with error code '0x80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.' This error was suppressed.

I don't have much previous experience with GPO, I'm a beginner so please write begineer-friendly responses, thank you!

Comment: That is common for hosts that do not wait for the network on startup. You either need to do that, or copy the installation file locally and execute from there

Comment: can you explain how did you Create it and with what path? creating as software is most more easier as other ways as you can upgrade from it until you remove the software

Answer (score 0):

I tried unchecking "install application at logon" and running the "gpupdate /force" command and it doesn't work neither, which should indicate the problem is not in "wait for the network on startup", right?

Screenshots:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xreyf745couqzm/Screen%20Shot%202021-06-04%20at%202.25.28%20AM.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u9sw71t37j236ed/Screen%20Shot%202021-06-04%20at%202.27.42%20AM.png?dl=0

Immediatelly after running "gpupdate /force", or after a logon (with "install app on logon" enabled), I get this error in event viewer:

The user 'Network' preference item in the 'Configure Users {EDD514E1-5797-42D0-9AA6-BCC7B00DFD14}' Group Policy Object did not apply because it failed with error code '0x80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.' This error was suppressed.

screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hjhh90sve0xp1pz/event_viewer.png?dl=0

I've put the MSI package in c:\share and shared that folder with: everyone, network computers, network.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0u8akuzufb4jvwd/network.png?dl=0

I checked from other computers in the network and they can all access this drive using the UNC path I entered.

It doesn't make sense that the problem is not having network access on logon, since I tried with the "gpupdate" command...

Also, I have enabled "always wait for the network on computer startup and logon" in local group policy editor...